# Bind a string in LongListSelector from MySQL database in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm new to Windows phone 8 esp when using the LongListSelector. I am trying to fetch a list from MySQL database and bind it in the LongListSelector. In my code it is only displaying the MessageBox dialog instead of fetching the list. What could be the problem. Or did I place my code for fetching the list in the wrong method. Please help..

The string to be binded to the LongListSelector is f1, 
the ListLongselector name= ListCompanies

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Set the data context of the LongListSelector control to the sample data
            DataContext = App.ViewModel;

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        // Load data for the ViewModel Items
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            //{
            //    App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            //}

            string url = "http://localhost/taxi/fetch_nrb.php";
            WebClient webclientmenu = new WebClient();
            webclientmenu.DownloadStringCompleted += webclientmenu_DownloadStringCompleted;
            webclientmenu.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
        }

        // Handle selection changed on LongListSelector
        private void MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //// If selected item is null (no selection) do nothing
            //if (MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem == null)
            //    return;

            //// Navigate to the new page
            //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + (MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel).ID, UriKind.Relative));

            //// Reset selected item to null (no selection)
            //MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem = null;


        }

        void webclientmenu_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            try
            {
                string list = e.Result;
                string[] final = list.Split('#');
                string f1 = final[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < f1.Length; i++)
                {
                    ListCompanies.ItemsSource.Add(f1[i]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check Your Internet Connectivity and try again later.\n No Network Connection", "Network Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK);

            }
        }
```

Comment: While you're displaying a message stating that there's a network connectivity issue but is that the actual exception that is thrown?

Comment: As suggested @MattLacey , check for the real exception. Is it `WebException`? If it is, most probably your emulator does not have internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to display a single character per list item ?

If yes I suggest replacing the foreach loop with :

```
ListCompanies.ItemsSource = f1;
```

if you want to display every string in final list with one string per item :

```
ListCompanies.ItemsSource = final;
```

You are encountering a notimplemented exception because the ItemsSource property is made to be assigned to a list you created.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this code;

```
// Load data for the ViewModel Items
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            //{
            //    App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            //}

            string url = "http://localhost/taxi/fetch_nrb.php";
            WebClient webclientmenu = new WebClient();
            webclientmenu.DownloadStringCompleted += webclientmenu_DownloadStringCompleted;
            webclientmenu.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
```

with this ;

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            {
                App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            }
        }
```

And make your load event with "LongListSelector_Loaded" event.
To do that, go your xaml side, click longlistselector, click events and double click "Loaded" box. Then go and write your requests under there, like this;

```
 private void MainLongListSelector_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost/taxi/fetch_nrb.php";
            WebClient webclientmenu = new WebClient();
            webclientmenu.DownloadStringCompleted += webclientmenu_DownloadStringCompleted;
            webclientmenu.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
```

good luck.